# Show tier price on home page in Magento

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-1.8, magento-enterprise, tierprice

I want to show price exclude and include in custom product slider in Magento home page. For this, I have tried almost all things but could not success below is my approach

In XML part I have added code:

```
<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.tierprices" template="productslider/best-seller.phtml">
    <action method="setTierPriceTemplate">
        <template>catalog/product/view/tierprices.phtml</template>
    </action>
</block>
```

And in code I have echo:

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $this->sku);
$price = $_product->getPrice();
$prices = $this->getTierPrices($_product);
```

or:

```
$this->getPriceHtml($_product, true);
```

But it doesn't show right price ex.vat and incl.vat

Please help me

Comment: Please show  layout xml code for  slider.

Answer (score 2):

### Edited:

***All the old solution is deleted.***

*Below solution,will works*.

1. In other **show tier prices** at anywhere,you need to first add tier price to that collection. So just add `addTierPriceData()` to that collection.
2. Then inside `foreach` loop of that collection add below code:

   ```
   $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_price')
       ->setTemplate('catalog/product/view/tierprices.phtml')
       ->setProduct($_product)
       ->setName('tier_' . $_product->getId())
       ->setInGrouped($_product->isGrouped())
       ->setParent(null)
       ->callParentToHtml();
   ```

This is show tier price like product details page.

**Example:**

Suppose, you want to show tier price at category & Catalog Search Page, then first add `addTierPriceData()` at [_getProductCollection](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php#L56)  function's [return value ( return $this->_productCollection->addTierPriceData();)](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php#L96)

Then at `list.phtml` inside `foreach` loop add below code:

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_price')
    ->setTemplate('catalog/product/view/tierprices.phtml')
    ->setProduct($_product)
    ->setName('tier_' . $_product->getId())
    ->setInGrouped($_product->isGrouped())
    ->setParent(null)
    ->callParentToHtml();
```

Comment: There is error :  Call to a member function setProductClassId() on a non-object in

Comment: have you  try with issue1 and issue2

Comment: I have use full code. Ok let me try there is any thing write in xml file ?

    <block type="catalog/product_view"  name="product.tierprices" template="productslider/best-seller.phtml">
<action method="setTierPriceTemplate><template>catalog/product/view/tierprices.phtml</template></action>
    </block>

Comment: wait .. i will give you  details which is not need the xml code

Comment: please try $this->getTierPriceHtml($_product).  It is work if your slider block class is extend from  Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract.No need the xml code..

Comment: ok let me try it

Comment: is my solution is work?

Comment: answer is edited.....

Answer (score 1):

To simply get all the tier prices you could try the following:

```
$prices = $product->getFormatedTierPrice();
```

The reason your call for $this->getTierPrices($_product); is not working, because your block is not of a type that extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract which contains this getTierPrices function.