# Display default price when tierprice is not available magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, tierprice

I have a customer, who has a tier price for almost every product in their webshop. But some products don't have a tier price. 
In `template/catalog/product/list.phtml the tier price` is added through this:

`<?php echo $this->gettierPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>`

Which displays template/catalog/product/view/tierprices.phtml

But how to show the default price when there is no tierprice for this product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be *tier price  does not implement properly  at list.phtml*.Check this answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/61439/4564. How to show *tier price at list.phtml*

In order show *default price at list.phtml* you need to call   `<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>`

### Solution:

```
 if($_product->getTierPrice()): 
 $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_price')
   ->setTemplate('catalog/product/view/tierprices.phtml')
            ->setProduct($_product)
      ->setName('tier_'.$_product->getId())           
            ->setInGrouped($_product->isGrouped())
            ->setParent(null)
            ->callParentToHtml();
 else:
  echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ;
endif;
```